# Jdbc Ms SQL Driver 3.0 callable statement using default parameters

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc

What is the best way to reuse a `CallableStatement`
I want to use the same `msp_updateOption` in different ways and make it reusable code.
Also the `CallableStatement` should take input as parameter type and not indexes.

```
private static final String UPDATE_INFO = "{call msp_updateOption (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
private static final String UPDATE__INFO_NO_COMMENT = "{call msp_updaterOption (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
private static final String UPDATE_INFO_NO_COMMENT_NO_G = "{call msp_updateOption (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

ALTER procedure [dbo].[msp_UpdateOption]
@pnbr int,
@pB datetime=null,
@stopFlag int,
@emailFlag int,
@name varchar(100),
@pName varchar(100),
@pID varchar(100),
@gNbr int=null,
@commentTypeID int=null,
@updateTypeID int
```

I tried implementing something like this: where map = `HashMap` having `name-value` pairs. `name` is `param name`.

```
Set set = map.keySet();
Iterator itr = set.iterator(); // iterate through HashMap values
// iterator
try {
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String paramType = (String) (itr.next());
        cstmt.setObject(paramType,map.get(paramType));
        cstmt.execute();
    }
```

while executing this , it always goees beyond the index defined for the sp and errors out.
Will this implementation work. It worked with the older version JDBC driver of MS SQL 
This is the error I get.

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 10 is out of range.
[10/20/11 18:56:25:082 CDT] 0000002d SystemOut     O    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
[10/20/11 18:56:25:082 CDT] 0000002d SystemOut     O    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:700)
[10/20/11 18:56:25:082 CDT] 0000002d SystemOut     O    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObjectNoType(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:896)
[10/20/11 18:56:25:082 CDT] 0000002d SystemOut     O    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.setObject(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:1379)
[10/20/11 18:56:25:082 CDT] 0000002d SystemOut     O    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcCallableStatement.setObject(WSJdbcCallableStatem
```